# Sending an iCalendar invite via Smtp

Tags: smtp, icalendar

I've been trying to send an iCalendar invite through smtp for a few days now. I'm using the DDay.iCal library to build the iCalendar component of the message and I'm using a more-or-less homegrown smtp server to send the message (unfortunately I'm stuck with this solution for the time being).

I've messed around with a few different ways of doing this and I haven't had any luck. The result is usually that the recipient gets an email with a .ics attachment. In outlook, i can open the attachment and add it to my calendar; gmail will only let me download the attachment. It doesn't recognize it as a calendar invite.

Below is an example of one of the scenarios I've tried. Can someone tell me what's wrong with it or what needs to be done to construct a proper calendar invite message?

Thanks!

```
Delivered-To: jordan_test@gmail.com
Received: by 10.68.224.234 with SMTP id rf10csp257513pbc;
    Mon, 27 Aug 2012 09:16:44 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.50.85.228 with SMTP id k4mr10905189igz.22.1346084204116;
    Mon, 27 Aug 2012 09:16:44 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <283877=jordan_test=gmail.com@smtp.mycompany.com>
Received: from smtp.mycompany.com ([214.16.251.150])
    by mx.google.com with SMTP id cw2si32587704icc.106.2012.08.27.09.16.43;
    Mon, 27 Aug 2012 09:16:44 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 214.16.251.150 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of 283877=jordan_test=gmail.com@smtp.mycompany.com) client-ip=215.16.251.150;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 215.16.251.150 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of 283877=jordan_test=gmail.com@smtp.mycompany.com) smtp.mail=283877=jordan_test=gmail.com@smtp.mycompany.com
Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2012 16:16:43 GMT
X-Mailer: BlahCommunicationsServices 1.0.0, by BLAH Inc.
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?SGV5ISB0aGlzIGlzIGZvciB5b3Uu?=
From: <ical@return.mycompany.com>
To: <jordan_test@gmail.com>
Reply-To: <ical@return.mycompany.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary="__=_Part_Boundary_1687780707_370337274"
Message-Id: <283877@smtp.mycompany.com>
References: <283877@smtp.mycompany.com>





--__=_Part_Boundary_1687780707_370337274
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain

test test test


--__=_Part_Boundary_1687780707_370337274
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/calendar;method=REQUEST;charset=utf-8

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=Jordan;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=TENTATIVE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:jordan@mycompany.com
ATTENDEE;CN=Jordan;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=TENTATIVE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:jordan_test@gmail.com
DESCRIPTION:test test test
DTEND:20120828T130000
DTSTAMP:20120827T121642
DTSTART:20120828T120000
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:ical@return.mycompany.com
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Hey! this is for you.
UID:234434
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
END:VTIMEZONE
END:VCALENDAR



--__=_Part_Boundary_1687780707_370337274--
```

Comment: By the by, listing your own Message-Id in References is decidedly weird. If a message us not part if a thread, don't put in a References header.

Comment: I'm only just familiarizing myself with RFC6047, but I'm wondering; shouldn't the MIME `method=` attribute match the `METHOD:` field in the body?

Comment: See also http://icalvalid.wikidot.com/ although it seems to want your calendar on a HTTP server, not in email.

Comment: http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/ complained about the empty `VTIMEZONE` snippet.

Comment: Thanks! The VTIMEZONE snippet was actually the problem. Interestingly, when I generated an iCal file with that snippet and saved it to my hard drive, outlook didn't complain when I opened it.

Comment: The other validator thought it was fine, too (there are links to two validators on the wikidot site; but the newer one is apparently an improved fork of the old one).

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer; I can hardly claim any credit here.